# Error Called a function from a directive inside a function in a Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I Have two controllers where i do almost the same thing, only change a little things in them, I have this:

```
app.controller('CreateSignerCtrl', ['$scope','SweetAlert','SignerResource','$http', '$location', '$routeParams','$timeout','ngDialog', function ($scope, SweetAlert, SignerResource, $http, $location, $routeParams, $timeout,ngDialog) {
            $scope.title = "Add Signer";
            $scope.button = "Save";
            $scope.Signer = {};
            $scope.cancel = ngDialog.closeAll;

            $scope.saveSigner = function() {
                SignerResource.save($scope.Signer);
                $.notify({
                    title: '<strong>Data Updated! </strong>',
                    message: 'Signer Updated.'
                },{
                    type: 'success',
                    placement: {
                        from: 'bottom',
                        align: 'right'
                    },
                    animate: {
                        enter: 'animated fadeInDown',
                        exit: 'animated fadeOutUp'
                    }
                });
                ngDialog.closeAll();
                $scope.getModelData();
            };
            $scope.save = $scope.saveSigner;
        }]);
```

In this controller when i called the function *$scope.saveSigner* i receive this error:

```
TypeError: $scope.getModelData is not a function
```

And in this Controller:

```
app.controller('EditSignerCtrl', ['$scope','SweetAlert','SignerResource','$http', '$location', '$routeParams','$timeout','ngDialog', function ($scope, SweetAlert, SignerResource, $http, $location, $routeParams, $timeout,ngDialog) {
        $scope.title = "Edit Signer";
        $scope.button = "Update";
        $scope.Signer = SignerResource.get({
            id: $scope.signerId
        });
        $scope.cancel = ngDialog.closeAll;

        $scope.updateSigner = function() {
            SignerResource.update($scope.Signer);
            $.notify({
                title: '<strong>Data Updated! </strong>',
                message: 'Signer Updated.'
            },{
                type: 'success',
                placement: {
                    from: 'bottom',
                    align: 'right'
                },
                animate: {
                    enter: 'animated fadeInDown',
                    exit: 'animated fadeOutUp'
                }
            });
            ngDialog.closeAll();
            $scope.getModelData();
        };

        $scope.save = $scope.updateSigner;
    }]);
```

In this controller all is executed fine and *$scope.getModelData* do not send me any error.

The Directive is this:

```
app.directive('datapaginator', function() {
  return {
    url: '=a',
    controller: function($scope, $http) {

        $scope.model = [];

        $scope.getModelData = function() {
            $http({
                url: $scope.url,
                method: "GET",
                params: {page:  $scope.currentpage || 1}
            }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                if($scope.currentpage > data.last_page){
                    $scope.currentpage = data.last_page;
                    $scope.getModelData();
                }
                $scope.currentpage = data.current_page;
                $scope.lastpage = data.last_page;
                $scope.generatePages(data.last_page);
                $scope.model = data.data;
            }).error(function(response) {
                $scope.model = response.error;
            });
        };
});
```

That function (*$scope.getModelData*) is executed many time in other controller and is executed without problem.

Comment: It seems the $scope in the CreateSignerCtrl controller isn't inherited from your directive. Isn't it better to move the getModelData function to a service?

Comment: Maybe but that function is a standar function to will use with any model parsing the url from the first Controller of the model or Service.

Answer (score 0):

I think your directive **datapaginator** is not included inside your ** CreateSignerCtrl** but it's included inside your **EditSignerCtrl**.

> You should check your markup to see if you are including your directive in both your controllers.
>
> However, I do think you should move your **getModelData** function to a service instead.

Read [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services). Hope I could help :)

Comment: is not that, the directive is not included in neither Controller

Comment: i try to update my view or the view that i have in that moment

Comment: I would like to see your markup if you could update your question with your html, I could better help solve your problem.

Comment: yeah dude, the html and the script ;)